# How to determine which content page requested in Master page

Tags: c#, asp.net, c#-4.0, master-pages

How I can determine which content page requested from master page load method?for ezample I have content pages that use a master page.How I can determine which of these three pages requsted by user from master page?

thanks

Comment: Just for clarification: your pages don't actually inherit from a master page, they just 'use' a master page. Pages inherit from System.Web.UI.Page.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can determine the content page from your master page by using the `ContentPlaceHolder's` Page property. The following code assumes that the content place holder on your master page is called `MainContent`.

```
// Page_Load in your master page code behind file
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  if (this.MainContent.Page is _Default)
  {
    // The default page
  }

  if (this.MainContent.Page is About)
  {
    // The About page.
  }
}
```

Comment: The `Master` page itself has the `Page` property, so you could change `this.MainContent.Page` to `this.Page` or simply `Page`.

Answer (score 1):

A [master page is actually a subclass of System.Web.UI.UserControl](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.masterpage.aspx) and as such it has a reference to the page through its [Page property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.control.page.aspx). For example, if you want to know the ASPX file and/or its folder, you can use the following code:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  // Something like ~/Folder/Default.aspx
  string file = Page.AppRelativeVirtualPath;

  // Something like ~/Folder/
  string folder = Page.AppRelativeTemplateSourceDirectory;
}
```

Comment: That would work, assuming you get exactly the right 'magic string' values to match against. When possible (which is usually), I would prefer to test against the type of the `Page` object.

Comment: Sure, and that's what [Hans' answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/8871025/4830) shows. I just wanted to add some extra info, in case the OP needs information about the ASPX file rather than the code-behind class.